# Seleção de registros relacionados com SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma que chama `grupo` onde é armazenado os grupos criados para acesso de uma aplicação. Por exemplo, se você tiver no grupo `CADASTRO_ADMIN`, você terá permissão total; agora, se tiver no grupo `CADASTRO_USR` terá permissão apenas de usuário.

A outra tabela se chama `grupo usuário`, onde fica armazenado o CPF do usuário junto com o seu grupo de permissão, vejam:

**GRUPO**

[image: grupo]

**GRUPO USUÁRIO**

[image: grupousuario]

O *select* que preciso fazer é o seguinte: Selecionar os grupos que o usuário é administrador junto com os grupos que possuem o código do grupo administrador na coluna `cod_grupo_admin`.

Por exemplo, o usuário `222.222.222-11` é administrador do grupo `18`, daí minha consulta precisa retornar o grupo `18`, `22` e `30`, pois tem o `cod_grupo_admin = 18`.

Tentei essa consulta, mas o problema que ele só me retorna o código do grupo `admin`, não os demais.

```
SELECT g.* FROM grupo g
LEFT JOIN grupo_usuario u ON (g.codigo = u.codigo_grupo)
WHERE
g.administrador = true AND u.cpf='222.222.222-11'
```

Comment: Pergunta: está utilizando MySQL ou PostgreSQL?

Comment: Opa, estou usando o PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não testei, mas creio que seja isso que você procura:

```
SELECT grupo.codigo
  FROM grupo
 INNER JOIN grupo_usuario ON (grupo.codigo = grupo_usuario.codigo_grupo)
 WHERE grupo_usuario.cpf = '...'
   AND grupo.administrador = true
UNION
SELECT grupo.codigo
  FROM grupo
 INNER JOIN grupo_usuario ON (grupo.cod_grupo_admin = grupo_usuario.codigo_grupo)
 WHERE grupo_usuario.cpf = '...'
```

Explicando um pouco:

O primeiro select pega o grupo em que o usuário é diretamente administrador.

O segundo pega os grupos que tem como grupo administrador o grupo do usuário.

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, não tenho muita experiência com consultas SQL. Me ajudou bastante, abraços!